# Xcode 7 UILable on UITableView disappear on CoreData project if add constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

**1.** I created a `Maste－Detail Application` project like below:

[image]

`2.` And drage a UILabel onto the cell like below:
[image]

3.Changed the code:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//    cell.textLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:11];
    label.text = [[object valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description];
}
```

**QUESTION:** The result is like this, actually the cell was created, but not sure where is the label?
[image]

But if i remove all the constraints, it works well, not sure why.
[image]

Comment: What constraints you have applied to label?

Comment: As the second image shows, it's inner ```contentView```